# Azure Resource Management API to directly return the number of resources within a subscription or resource group?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Is there an Azure Resource Management API to directly get the number of resources (preferably can be filtered by certain criteria like resource types) within a subscription or resource group?

I know there are ARM APIs to get a list of resources within a subscription or resource group ([this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list) and [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list-by-resource-group)). But I don't want to retrieve a huge list (potentially paginated) just to count the number of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Resource Graph API, something documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureresourcegraph/resourcegraph(2021-03-01)/resources/resources#filter-resources

---

Using UI (example only here):

[image]